# Time Complexity of init function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to remove the last element of a list in Haskell and have found out about the `init` function. Since the function that I am using it in has to be O(n) I would like to know what the time complexity of `init` is.

Comment: Init runs in *O(n)* given you fully expand it. Since Haskell is lazy, the function call itself runs in *O(1)*, but evaluating it to a "materialized" list, will require *O(n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem seems like that's all there is to answer here...

Comment: Lists are shaped like Russian nesting dolls. What's the time complexity to remove the innermost doll? Be sure to click through to implementations of functions from the haddocks. Almost everything in Prelude and Data.List are simple 2 to 3 line haskell functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`init :: [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:init) is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#init):

> ```
> init [] =  errorEmptyList "init"
> init (x:xs) =  init' x xs
>   where init' _ [] = []
>         init' y (z:zs) = y : init' z zs
> ```

In order to generate a list, it will thus iterate over the source list, each time looking one element ahead and emitting the previous one, given the tail is not the empty list.

This thus means that for a list of *n* elements, it will take *O(n)* time to calculate the `init` of that list.

In Haskell function calls are however lazy. If you are, for example, only interested in taking the first `k` elements, it will run in *O(* min(*n*, *k*) *)*.

Comment: maybe add that "`init` is productive"? laziness alone doesn't account for the behavior you describe so that might be confusing